# Restart download using `nsIWebBrowserPersist saveURI` or something else in a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, download

Mozzila has [sample code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Downloading_Files) for using [`nsIWebBrowserPersist saveURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebBrowserPersist#saveURI%28%29) to download files from a Firefox extension.

However, it doesn't say how to monitor if the download stops and needs to be restarted again.

Is there some way to check if the download stops and restart the download again? If I can't do it with `nsIWebBrowserPersist`, can I use something else?

Comment: Is it obligatory to use `nsIWebBrowserPersist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement and [`nsIWebProgressListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebProgressListener) and [`.progressListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebBrowserPersist#Attributes).

Your listener must implement all `nsIWebProgressListener` methods, but you can just stub out most of them. The important one (for this question) is `onStateChange`, where you can check for an error result which will indicate network errors, and, as the documentation states, also check for the server returning http error:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
var mylistener = {
  QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener]),
  ...
  onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStateFlags, aStatus) {
    if (!(aStateFlags & Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP)) {
      // not yet done.
    }
    aWebProgress.progressListener = null; // reset to avoid circular references -> leaks
    if (!Components.isSuccessCode(aStatus)) {
      // Some network or file related error happened.
    }
    if (aRequest instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel && aRequest.responseStatus >= 400) {
      // Some http related error happened.
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Is there some way to get download progress in `onStateChange`?

Comment: And sometimes the server closes the connection for some unknown reasons, but the code doesn't seem to be able to catch this error.

Answer (score 1):

[Downloads.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm) supports resuming downloads. Set tryToKeepPartialData on your [Downloads object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm/Download).